# Is it possible to dynamically change view name or create a view that does not exist yet in phalcon?

Tags: php, phalcon, volt, phalcon-routing

I would like to know how can i do this in phalcon. I have a web site build with phalcon. All is working great now i stumbled upon a problem, here is what i need.

When a user clicks on a post that was created by another user. It takes him to this post with pictures and all things he entered to DB. I would like that in browser the name of this view is not like www.website.com/posts/index but that it is like www.website.com/posts/Nameofthepost, and like that for each other postings on the website. So that all posts (really ads) show their name up in browser. I hope i wrote everything understandable.

Appreciate all suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That has to do with routing doesn't it? I modified this from my own code, I used grouping, you don't have to. I didn't test this code.

```php
// routes.php

$router = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Router();
$router->setDefaultModule("__YOUR_MODULE__");
$router->removeExtraSlashes(true);

... your other routes ...

// posts group

$posts = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Router\Group(array(
    'module' => '__YOUR_MODULE__',
    'controller' => 'posts',
    'action' => 'index'
));

// All the routes start with /post
$posts->setPrefix('/post');

$posts->add('/{postName}/:params', array(
    'action' => 'index',
    'params' => 2
));

// Maybe this will be enough for your needs, 
// the one above has a catch all params, which
// has to be manually parsed
$posts->add('/{postName}', array(
    'action' => 'index',
));

$posts->add('[/]*', array(
    'action' => 'index',
));
$router->mount($posts);
unset($posts);

... other routes ...

return $router;
```

On your controller, you can get the `postName` param this way:

```
$this->dispatcher->getParam('permaPath');
```

As shown in the phalcon routing documentation, you can use regex in your routing config, something like this?

```
$posts->add('/{postName:[-0-6_A-Za-z]+}/:params', array(
    'action' => 'index',
    'params' => 2
));
```

So, only `-_`, `0-9`, `A-Z`, `a-z` allowed for `postName`. If the URL had a comma in there or something, then route doesn't match, 404 page not found.